# C# Change Form Width/Height With Textbox Entry?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Is there any way to reverse this code so that the user can set the windows form width/height via a textbox entry?

```
textBox1.Text = this.Width.ToString();
```

I'm coding in c#

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106421/winforms-resize-a-window-but-only-allow-change-of-height

Comment: Well do you mean something like `this.Bounds = new Rectangle(0,0,Width,Height);` ?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Thanks V4Vendetta that worked perfectly :)

Comment: @MatthewAllen Added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by setting the Bounds of your form

`this.Bounds = new Rectangle(0,0,Width,Height);`

pass in the `Width` and `Height` as captured from the `TextBox` and this should help you set the form height width.